# get label text from cell at row

Tags: swift, xcode

is there another way i can get the string from the `refinementslabel.text` when I call did select row , because i think/apparently in the new `XCode` calling
`let serviceTypeCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! ServiceCell`

crashes my app

so i am looking for code like
`let text = refinementsLabel.text at indexpath.row`

but I'm not sure exactly what to type?

```
let sections = ["All Users & Services","Automotive", "Building & Construction", "Cleaning", "Landscaping & Gardening"]

let services = [["All Users & Services"],["Automotive"],["Air Conditioning & Heating","Bricklaying", "Carpentry","Carpet Layer","Concreting & Paving","Electrical","Fencing and Gates","Flooring","Handyman","Other","Painting & Decorating","Pet Control","Plastering","Plumbing","Roofing","Rubbish Removal","Scaffolding","Tiling"], ["Cleaning"],["Landscaping & Gardening"]]

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let serviceTypeCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! ServiceCell
    var service = serviceTypeCell.refinementsLabel.text
    service = services[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

defaults.set(service, forKey: "Service being searched")
    guard let serviceBeingSearched = self.defaults.string(forKey: "Service being searched") else { return }
    navigationItem.title = serviceBeingSearched
     tableView.reloadData()

}
```

Comment: Hi there- surely you should be querying the model (ie the data source) for the collection view rather than the collection view itself?

Comment: Don't call `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:)` outside `cellForRowAtIndexPath()`. If it's a label, you already know with `section` and `services` array and the `indexPath`, no need to use a cell. Don't rely on UI for that, rely on your model. If you really still want to acce the UI, use `cellForRow()`, but it will crash if the cell is not visible.

Answer (score 0):

Below method is using when create new cell that method is use in `cellforRow` if you are using that method than app crash

```
let serviceTypeCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! ServiceCell
```

If you get cell in `didselect` method you can use below code

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? ServiceCell
```

if you get string from you can select cell than use below line

```
let service = services[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
```